# How to create custom groupBy aggregator?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create my own variance function to calculate the variance during a DataFrame groupBy aggregate step. I can't use the functions.variance() method because the size of inputs is stored in a column. I want to find the variance of a column "PercentEaten" where the total number of items is stored in a column named "NumberOfItems".

I am confused on how to create my own function that returns a Column type as the .agg() method requires functions with Column return types.

Here is an example of what I am looking for

```
myDF.groupBy(col("Store"), col("week")).agg(sum(col("PercentEaten")).divide(col("NumberOfItems")).as("MeanPercentEaten"), myVariance(col("PercentEaten"), col("NumberOfItems")).as("VariancePercentEaten");
```

I am just uncertain on how to go about defining myVariance() method. This is also my first time using Spark so my style of coding might not be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am just uncertain on how to go about defining myVariance() method.

That's an example of a **user-defined aggregate function** (aka UDAF).

To create one you have to implement [org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/UserDefinedAggregateFunction.html):

> The base class for implementing user-defined aggregate functions (UDAF).

After that you should create an instance of the custom UDAF and use `apply` or `distinct` methods to use it.

> **apply(Column... exprs)** Creates a Column for this UDAF using given Columns as input arguments.
>
> **distinct(Column... exprs)** Creates a Column for this UDAF using the distinct values of the given Columns as input arguments.

---

(I'm not going to present any code as Java is not my language for Spark).

Comment: Does UDAF works on pyspark? It seems that there is only df.groupBy().agg()

Comment: I know nothing about pyspark. Why would `df.groupBy().agg()` make a UDF not work on pyspark?

Comment: can I use a column from one aggregator in another aggregator? For example df.groupBy().agg(mean(col().as("Mean"), variance(col(),col("Mean)); So us the Mean column which was created during aggregation in the variance aggregator?

Comment: @mjsee yes. I think that begs for another question, doesn't it? You could see the solution then ;-)